# PowerDNS - SOA serial mismatch on slaves

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, powerdns, soa-record

I am using PowerDNS with the PostgreSQL backend on three different servers, in native mode, all replication is done at the PostgreSQL backend. No server is set as master, `pdns.conf` is almost in default settings.

When I create a new zone using the PowerDNS API on the first server, I can see the zone and records in all three databases. And when using `dig SOA example.com @SERVER.IP` I receive a response from all servers, but with different SOA serials:

The first server which is the "primary" server and configured as such in the SOA record, has the SOA record `2020081503`, the two others `2020081505`.

When making changes to the zone, the serial is increasing, but the offset of 2 stays the same.

All servers are configured the same, except that the first one has the API and web server enabled in `pdns.conf`, and that it is mentioned in the SOA record.

Any idea where the offset comes from and how it can be synced?

Thank you!

Comment: Or, alternatively... is the SOA mismatch only there when querying powerdns or also if you examine the table data in postgresql?

Comment: Hi, only when querying the SOA record. I have compared the databases (tables: domains, domainmetadata and records) ... all entries are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

> When making changes to the zone, the serial is increasing, but the offset of 2 stays the same.

I found behavior like this, when default-soa-edit=INCEPTION-INCREMENT in the pdns.conf